# .LinkFormat.BreakLink not working on PowerPoint VBA Mac

Tags: vba, macos, powerpoint

I am creating a macro to update linked images within a PPT with a new filepath. The code works and all of the images update. However, if I delete the source files and just keep the .pptx file, the images revert to an old version. But, if I scroll through the slides that are being updated, before deleting the source files, the images stay updated to the new version. I have deleted the template files also.

I have tried .LinkFormat.BreakLink from the documentation and it gives me a Method or data member not found error. I have searched around for many answers and nothing seems to work. I do not know if this is a Mac issue or not. Is there a way to simulate scrolling through the slides? I have tried a loop function, but that doesn't seem to work. Maybe I'm not doing it correctly. Does anybody have any ideas?

Note: filepaths have been changed, for privacy purposes.

```
Sub EditPowerPointLinks()

Dim oldFilePath As String
Dim newFilePath As String
Dim pptPresentation As Presentation
Dim pptSlide As Slide
Dim pptShape As Shape
Dim idnName As String
Dim saveName As String
Dim folderName As String
     

folderName = ActivePresentation.Path

longName = Right(folderName, Len(folderName) - 81)
idnName = Left(longName, Len(longName) - 3)

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = idnName
ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = idnName & " | 2023"

'The old file path as a string (the text to be replaced)
oldFilePath = "FilePath/Folder/"

'The new file path as a string (the text to replace with)
newFilePath = ActivePresentation.Path & "/"

'Set the variable to the PowerPoint Presentation
Set pptPresentation = ActivePresentation

'Loop through each slide in the presentation
For Each pptSlide In pptPresentation.Slides

    'Loop through each shape in each slide
    For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
   
        'Find out if the shape is a linked object or a linked picture
        If pptShape.Type = msoLinkedPicture Or pptShape.Type _
        = msoLinkedOLEObject Or pptShape.Type = msoLinkedChart Then

            'Use Replace to change the oldFilePath to the newFilePath
            pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = Replace(LCase _
            (pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName), LCase(oldFilePath), newFilePath)
            
        End If
    Next
Next


'Update the links
pptPresentation.UpdateLinks

    For Each pptShape In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
        With pptShape
            If .Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
                .LinkFormat.Update
                .LinkFormat.BreakLink
            End If
        End With
    Next pptShape


With ActivePresentation
    .SaveAs _
        FileName:=folderName & "/" & longName & "_file.pptx", _
        FileFormat:=ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation
    .SaveAs _
        FileName:="filepath/folder" & "/" & longName & "_file.pptx", _
        FileFormat:=ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation
End With



Kill (folderName & "/" & "z_file.pptx")

With Application.Presentations(folderName & "/" & longName & "_file.pptx")

    .Saved = True

    .Close

End With

Set pptApp = Nothing
Set pptPresentation = Nothing
Set pptSlide = Nothing
Set pptShape = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: >>I have tried .LinkFormat.BreakLink from the documentation and it gives me a Method or data member not found error. >>  Mac doesn't support all the linking options that Windows does, and since the same command does work in the Windows version, I think you've hit one of those Windows, Yes; Mac, No issues.

Comment: Thank you Steve, I thought I was going crazy! haha. I ended up just using vba to insert the images and forget about links all together. It was doing nothing but causing problems.